# Dismiss UIAlertController keyboard in Swift 2.3

Tags: ios, swift, keyboard, uialertcontroller

I recently upgraded to latest Xcode version and converted my project to Swift 2.3. Until 2.2, when I displayed an `UIAlertController` I dismissed the keyboard with the classic

```
override func touchesBegan(touches: Set<UITouch>, withEvent event: UIEvent?){ 
   view.endEditing(true)         
   super.touchesBegan(touches, withEvent: event)
}
```

Well, it doesn't work anymore. Tried to change textView's `UIKeyboardType`  and `returnKeyType`. No luck. Any thoughts?

Comment: Have you checked this? http://stackoverflow.com/q/26161796/1689376

Comment: when alert is presented `touchesBegan` is not fired as alert's background view overlaps your complete self.view. It works with keyboard because keyboard is half presented.

Comment: alexburtnik: Thanks for the link. Rajan Maheshwari: you are right. My UIAlertController was too big and its controls were hidden by the keyboard "predictive" mode. I shrinked it and it worked fine. Thanks.

Comment: Try out this [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24126678/close-ios-keyboard-by-touching-anywhere-using-swift)
Hope this helps you out. Happy coding

Answer (score 0):

Try to use a tapGesture Recognizer for the View. Try out this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24126678/close-ios-keyboard-by-touching-anywhere-using-swift)

Or you can try out this Code:

```
override func touchesBegan(touches: Set<UITouch>, withEvent event: UIEvent?)
{        
super.touchesBegan(touches, withEvent: event)
view.endEditing(true)  
}
```

Hope this helps you out. Happy coding